# djangowebsocketredis and nginx failing on Django 1.7

Tags: django, nginx, websocket

A running project on Ubuntu with nginx 1.7.10-1chl1

```
Django==1.6
uWsgi==2.0.6
django-redis-sessions==0.4.0
django-websocket-redis==0.4.1
```

was upgraded to Django==1.7, we tried updating django-websocket-redis to 0.4.2 and master, changed uWsgi to 2.0.3 and 2.0.9 but none of the combinations worked

We got errors on the log like:

```
2015/02/12 17:37:43 [error] 11229#0: *11 upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: ,  request: "GET /notificaciones/main?subscribe-user HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///tmp/websocket.sock:/notificaciones/main?subscribe-user"
```

meanwhile the clients show messages like

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line main.min.a0f614466a16.js:342 Websocket connection is broken!
```

The nginx configuration is

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/websocket.sock;
}
```

When the project is run as runserver we do not get problems, but when in production we started to see them.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, can you post the answer?  I have the same config as you, and am having the same problem.

Comment: I guess Camilo Nova http://axiacore.com/blog/author/camilo-nova/